# How to store complex data struts in Memcache

Tags: c, ruby, memcached

I have a data struts like this:

```
category:
  subcategory:
    color:red
    name:pen
```

Is there any better method to store if i want to load such data in memcache? or Is there any other better memory database?

Thanks!

Comment: How can we give you a better method if you don't tell us which one you're using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save what you want in your Memcache, if it's Marshable.

Your struts seems to be a Hash so it's really easy to do.

You can try something like Redis to store that. Or even all Document oriented Database like MongoDB too.

Answer (score 1):

or for more complexity you can use sqlite and run it in memory mode.